# Python, multi-threading - RuntimeError: cannot notify on un-acquired lock

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to create a simple code which is able to generate odd and even numbers by using multi-threading. There are many ways of doing it, but I am trying to implement a lock, mainly for learning purposes.
Here's my code:

```
from threading import *
from time import sleep

class Even:
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = Condition()

    def evenNumbers(self):
        self.c.acquire()
        for i in range(0, 101, 2):
            print("Even : ", i)
            self.num = i
            sleep(1.)
            self.c.notify()
            self.c.release()
            
            
class Odd:
    def __init__(self, even):
        self.even = even

    def oddNumbers(self):
        self.even.c.acquire()
        print("Odd : ", self.even.num+1)
        sleep(1.)
        self.even.c.notify()
        self.even.c.release()

tEven = Even()
tOdd = Odd(tEven)

t1 = Thread(target=tEven.evenNumbers)
t2 = Thread(target=tOdd.oddNumbers)

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

and I get the following error

> Exception in thread Thread-6:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
> self.run()
> File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
> File "", line 14, in evenNumbers
> self.c.notify()
> File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 346, in notify
> raise RuntimeError("cannot notify on un-acquired lock")
> RuntimeError: cannot notify on un-acquired lock

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `wait()` calling. Because `notify()` wakes up only thread **waiting** for the condition variable.

```
from threading import *
from time import sleep


class Even:
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = Condition()

    def evenNumbers(self):
        self.c.acquire()
        for i in range(0, 101, 2):
            print("Even : ", i)
            self.num = i
            sleep(1.)
            self.c.notify()
            self.c.wait()
        self.c.release()


class Odd:
    def __init__(self, even):
        self.even = even

    def oddNumbers(self):
        self.even.c.acquire()
        for i in range(1, 100, 2):
            print("Odd : ", i)
            self.num = i
            sleep(1.)
            self.even.c.notify()
            self.even.c.wait()
        self.c.release()


tEven = Even()
tOdd = Odd(tEven)

t1 = Thread(target=tEven.evenNumbers)
t2 = Thread(target=tOdd.oddNumbers)

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have your call to `acquire` outside of the loop:

```
def evenNumbers(self):
    self.c.acquire()
    for i in range(0, 101, 2):
        print("Even : ", i)
        self.num = i
        sleep(1.)
        self.c.notify()
        self.c.release()
```

So that when you call `release` within the loop you are never calling `acquire` again. Move the call to `acquire` to be inside the loop:

```
def evenNumbers(self):
    for i in range(0, 101, 2):
        self.c.acquire()
        print("Even : ", i)
        self.num = i
        sleep(1.)
        self.c.notify()
        self.c.release()
```

Comment: You use `Condition` as `Lock`. `notify` is redundant in this case

Comment: I did get rid of the error message, but this does not generate a reasonable output.

Comment: @Phys This is very true. I was only addressing the exception. Issuing calls to `notify` when nobody is doing a `wait` doesn't make much sense.